# Microsoft Word find/replace regex bug

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, regex, wildcards

I'm trying to replace normal apostrophes with smart ones, but the replace function offsets the `’` to the wrong side of the character.

My expression:

> Find what: `'([a-z])`
>
> Replace with: `’\1`

Example:

> Found: I**'m** sorry.
>
> Replaced with: I**m’** sorry.

If anyone else has experienced this bug, and has found a workaround, I'd greatly appreciate some help. This exact expression was working earlier, and I'm not sure what went wrong.

Comment: I tried it here by copy/pasting your information and it works properly. `Microsoft Word 2016 MSO (16.0.9001.2080) 32-bit`

Comment: Have you tried with a lookahead (`'(?=[a-z])`)?